# Updating Firefox addon jsm module code without browser restart

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, xpcom, jsm

I am developing a Firefox addon that is loaded from a directory instead of an xpi, Firefox extension proxy file. The extension is based on jsm modules.

Is there a way to update those modules to reflect the code changes. The only way to do it now is to close and restart the browser but that its not a sane way to develop anything.

Tried to:

```
    Components.utils.unload('resource://myextension/mymodule.jsm');
    Components.utils.import('resource://myextension/mymodule.jsm');
```

but changes are not made.

Answer (score 1):

Got the answer from Victor Porof. In order to make this work you need to clear first the cache:

```
var obs = Cc["@mozilla.org/observer-service;1"].getService(Ci.nsIObserverService);
obs.notifyObservers(null, "startupcache-invalidate", null);
```

Hope this helps anyone

Comment: Thank you Victor Porof. I have been blessed by your answer :)